# Gatsby styles are not working in production build

Tags: gatsby

Running `npm run dev` works fine, but `npm run build` to create a `production` build creates an empty `styles.css` file in the `public` build folder.

`npm run serve` ends up with a website with no styles because it imports the empty `styles.css`.

I tried the `gatsby-plugin-postcss-sass` and `gatsby-plugin-sass` configured in `gatsby-config.js` as follows:

```
{
  resolve: "gatsby-plugin-postcss-sass",
  // resolve: "gatsby-plugin-sass",
  options: {
    includePaths: [
      path.resolve(__dirname, './node_modules'),
    ],
    postCssPlugins: [
      autoprefixer({
        browsers: ['last 2 versions'],
      })
    ]
  }
},
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So it turns out Gatsby is using Webpack 1 and I had somehow ended up with `"extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0"` and that version is only compatible with Webpack 3.

After I tried `yarn add extract-text-webpack-plugin@^1.0.1`, `npm run clean` and `npm run build`, the styles.css is now filled with CSS and `serve` shows the website with styles.